# trying to remove [ ] when printing an input jupyter 2.7

Tags: python

```
import datetime
year = int(datetime.date.today().year)
age = int(raw_input("How old are you? "))
age_100 = [(year - age) + 100]
print ("You will be 100 years old in " + .join(age_100))
```

error File "", line 5
    print ("You will be 100 years old in " + .join(age_100))
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I'm trying to remove the [] around the year when i print this.  i read on stack overflow that you can use the .join function to do this but it just gives me this error point to the .join?  i'm not sure why.

Comment: `+ .join` this is not valid

Comment: If you want to remove the `[]`, don't make `age_100` a list: `age_100 = (year - age) + 100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime
year = int(datetime.date.today().year)
age = int(raw_input("How old are you? "))
age_100 = (year - age) + 100

print ("You will be 100 years old in {0}".format(age_100))
```

- You do not need `[]` in `[(year - age) + 100]` (list)
- use `str.format` to join the string.

Comment: So that worked but can you explain what the {0} did?

Comment: I am just assigning first element of format to the string. ex `print("{0}---{1}".format("One", "Two"))` will print  `One---Two`